# Framework7 virtual list searchAll function not being used

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap, html-framework-7

I've got a PhoneGap application in development where I'm trying to use framework7's search bar to filter out my virtual list of products.

Current functionality is that the list works fine, but the search bar only searches through the rendered elements rather than the whole virtual list.

I've gone through framework7's [documentation](http://framework7.io/docs/virtual-list.html#using-with-search-bar) on getting their virtual list and searchbars to work together, but as far as I can tell the searchbar in my code completely ignores the virtual lists searchAll function which I put in. I can have searchAll() return anything and it makes no difference to the current functionality.

```
    var listObject = {
        items: selectProd,
        template: '<li class="item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div data-value="{{model_id}}" class="item-title list-title">{{internal_descriptn}}</div></div></li></script>',
        searchAll: function (query, items) {
            var foundItems = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                // Check if title contains query string
                if (items[i].title.indexOf(query.trim()) >= 0) foundItems.push(i);
            }
            // Return array with indexes of matched items
            return foundItems;
        }
    };
    console.log(listObject);
    var virtualList = myApp.virtualList('#product-list', listObject);
    var mySearchbar = myApp.searchbar('.searchbar', {
        searchList: '.list-block-search',
        searchIn: '.list-title'
    });
```

I feel like the only thing I could be missing is some way to put the virtualList into the searchbar as an attribute or similar to link them, it seems strange for me to expect them to just work together like magic. Yet that seems to be what the documentation suggests it does (not in my case apparently or it would work). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by looking at an [example](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/blob/master/kitchen-sink-ios/js/kitchen-sink.js) on their github. At first glance everything is the same, so I copy it over and slowly change it back to include my data to see where the problem occurs. For some godamn reason, you need to use the class virtual-list to identify the parent containing your list. Then specify that class for your virtual list and for your search bar. Using a different name instead won't work. Very frustrating that this isn't mentioned anywhere at all in documentation.